# Why do my humongous cliff ledges have cultivable soil on them?

Tags: science-based, geology, flora, erosion, soil

This world is basically a huge vertical cliff wall, hundreds of kilometers high. Some of the crevices and ledges in that wall are large enough to build cities on (up to kilometers in length and up to 500 meters wide). That's the largest horizontal surfaces available in this world, the chasm is literally bottomless.

How can such a world have cultivable soil on those ledges and crevices that can have things growing in it like trees or crops, if by logic erosion by wind and water from rains should flush everything off the cliffs into *Below* (which is inhospitably dangerous to all life even if there *is* a normal flat land somewhere down there)?

The technology level is somewhere around the late 19th century. No magic. Explanations that propose natural solutions are highly desirable over artificial means, since the people should've been able to survive and have agriculture in these conditions *before* inventing these artificial means to create and retain soil.

Comment: Are you sure you need to explain this? Unless your story hinges on geological detail I'm guessing that people are only going to notice if you disrupt the narrative to attempt to explain the geology.

Comment: Did you really just asked "do you need to worldbuild?" on a site dedicated to worldbuilding? =D I won't _need_ to explain it, but the internal explanation might butterfly some interesting changes to my worldbuilding an\or design of the place, I feel it's important enough to ask.

Comment: It helps that plant roots tend to hold soil in place. That said, where are the wind and water coming from?

Comment: I didn't say "Don't build your world?" I asked "Are you sure you need an explanation for a feature of your world?" Sometimes it's better to just show the world instead of telling people about it. I'd guess that in the 19th century the knowledge of soil formation was an flawed science.

Comment: Beware of atmospheric pressure. The cliff may be hundreds of kilometers high, but the narrow zone where atmospheric pressure is reasonable will be only about 5 km tall, and conditions will vary dramatically across those five vertical kilometers.

Comment: @AlexP How did you derive the lower bound for the human habitable range? I don't think we know of a depth below sea level in open air where humans experience negative effects.

Comment: @sphennings: I didn't derive it, I guesstimated. But if I am to derive it, I would say about 7 km below sea level. Nitrogen narcosis becomes noticeable at pressures above 2 atmospheres, and above 4 atmospheres it becomes impairing. 2 atmospheres would be the pressure of air at a depth of about 6.5 km below sea level; and 4 atmospheres at about 13 km below sea level. We don't have such deep depressions on Earth. On the shores on the Dead Sea, at about 400 meters below sea level, the pressure is about 1.05 atmospheres, which is of course perfectly fine.

Comment: @sphennings: [Air pressure at altitude calculator](https://www.mide.com/air-pressure-at-altitude-calculator).

Comment: Logic may suggest that everything on the ledges is flushed away.  Observation of real cliff ledges says there's a flaw in the logic :-)

Comment: Science-based, yea? There's a thing called compressive strength that, for rocks under gravity, determines how high a mountain can be (or how deep a chasm) before its base starts to crumble and round up in the planet spheroid. On Earth conditions, that's about 10 km high. So either your planet has quote a low gravity, or the rocks are extraordinary tough. If the latter, not much chances of erosion. If the former... I'll need a dissapointing answer for the computations of how weak the gravity should be for "a huge vertical cliff wall, hundreds of kilometers high" to resist crumbling down

Comment: How high a mountain can possibly get? https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9745/how-high-can-a-mountain-possibly-get

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi The cliff itself isn't entirely natural, its ordinary rock formations with scifi superstrong material underneath that they use as support (the entire thing is a planetary-scale megastructure going through a gas giant), so the height is handwaved away in that fashion.

Comment: @DarthBiomech I give up. Gas giants will have higher gravitational intensity than Earth and gasses which will be liquid, supercritical or solid on a span of altitude going over hundreds of kilometers. Can't build an answer on a science-based basis. What's wrong with a horizontal platform floating on top of the atmosphere? Other than less opportunities to weave stories in a mundane, almost trivial technologically setup.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Saturn's gravitational pull is actually just a wee bit over 1G. The structure in question has only the are near the top be habitable, where the atmospheric pressure is similar to Earth's, with the tip protruding above the breathable atmosphere and Below being depths where no light can reach and temperature and pressures are too high to live. What exactly is science-defying there, other than a planet-piercing megastructure capable of holding it all up?

Comment: @Darth Biomech: You've just re-invented Larry Niven's Mount Lookitthat. https://larryniven.fandom.com/wiki/Plateau

Comment: @DarthBiomech "a bit over 1G... What exactly is science-defying there?" because the atmosphere of Saturn (or any low density gas giant) is mostly hydrogen with a 3% bit of helium seasoning. Not very conducive to an Earth like biology. If you replace it with nitrogen/oxygen/carbon dioxide (not to mention water), you'll get a higher pressure, lower thickness/volume atmosphere and way higher G. Besides, gas giants are notorious for their storms - even the mostly tame Uranus have permanent winds at about 300km/h, with storms at 800km/h. Weather-shaping those rocks? It ain't water that does it.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi well, the giant itself is mostly hydrogen, but since there's a megastructure at play, it for some unknown reason slowly converts the giant into an oxygen-nitrogen one, generating breathable atmosphere and water that run down the sides of it towards the core. So only the space closer to the spire is habitable. It's also at the pole, where winds are parallel to the surface and not so severe. https://wiki.leavingthecradle.com/wiki/File:Spindle_artifact.jpg

Comment: @DarthBiomech quite a lot of missing details in your question. Framed like this, it becomes a reasonable frame to work in.

Comment: @DarthBiomech on the spindle artifact, the soil is just the decomposed bodies of the Ancients who where killed by the explosions of the mixture between pre-existing hydrogen and fabricated oxygen down draft. Perhaps they came out on the ledges to relax after a day's work or admire the cloudscape and there was always one of them to lit a cigar; next everyone knew, they were a slime sticking on the vertical wall of the spindle.

Comment: @DarthBiomech 'Did you really just asked "do you need to worldbuild?" on a site dedicated to worldbuilding' <- Good Worldbuilding should always include this question.  There is a threshold in Worldbuilding where things become so fantastical, that any attempt to explain a thing in detail only makes it less believable. When Gene Rodenberry was asked how inertial dampeners work, his response was "Very well".  He needed inertial dampeners for Star Trek to make any since, but lacking any pseudo-scientific basis for them, he just defined his setting as having them, and left it at that.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Eeeh, no, the only limit for the worldbuilding is your "resolution scale" and time budget. It isn't necessary and even wrong to include everything into the story, but you ideally need to have at least a rough idea about how everything important in your world functions. You don't need to explain how the dampeners work, but you do need to explain what's their general function principle and where's the limits of what they can do. Do that, and you won't need to have teleporter breaking every other episode in order to strand the crew on the planet ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cascading Water Falls

Waterfalls cause more erosion where they land than they do up or down stream which creates natural troughs.  The waterfalls bring in mineral sediment, and the erosion patterns they create will create natural bowl shapes in the rock face that will retain these sediments over time.  So your flat lands will over time develop lakes on the wall side and levees on the chasm side.  As the flow of water changes over time, some of these waterfalls will slow down to a trickle leaving large sediment rich areas of dry land on the chasm side, and retaining small lakes for irrigation on the other side... or perhaps it is like the Nile and it floods seasonally bringing in fresh mineral sediment every year, then mostly drying up for growing season.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In a word: poop.

Specifically bat poop. Guano is some great stuff for growing, among other things. And of course, bird poop.

You say:

> if by logic erosion by wind and water from rains should flush
> everything off the cliffs into Below (which is inhospitably dangerous
> to all life even if there is a normal flat land somewhere down there)?

By that logic, no highland anywhere would ever have any arable land. Which is not true.

But you also say:

> Some of the crevices and ledges in that wall are
> large enough to build cities on (up to kilometers in length and up to
> 500 meters wide).

And that this is the only flat land. So things might live there. And living things, from cows to humans do poop. And a flat area that big means that stuff from above that would end up caught there. So, that's soil. That's growth.

What you haven't mentioned is...sunlight? How are they getting that?

For civilization, I would be putting soil and plants on moving carts to catch the sun. Sun will be more valuable than anything else. Some crops can grow in shadow or on the edge of a shadow that gives way to sunlight, but not all, and if plants have adapted to these conditions there should be some stuff that doesn't need as much sun.

Answer (score 2):

Wind could work to deposit fine material onto the floor of crevices. When biological material mixed with this fine rock you get some fertile soil. And water can't wash it away because the soil is in a crevice. It just falls in front of it. hardy plants can spread from these more sheltered places. to the more inhospitable ledge-crevice combination. Just a couple of small loose rocks making a little sheltered spot just big enough for a single grass seedling would be enough of a start. Just having that single plant established stabilises that small bunch of soil. Enough that only storm like winds and fast flowing water would have a hope in taking that soil away. In fact slower moving winds would deposit some fine material into the crevices made by the plant. Increasing the available amount of soil and allowing for growth. This process will slowly cover the entire plateau. Parts can and would get washed away. But so long as it is just parts and life has been able to recover then those area's washed away would only temporarily be uncovered by plants.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loess

Answer (score 1):

Erosion isn't that uniform; your ledges won't be completely flat.

There's several ways that erosion might create sheltered nooks where life could evolve. Erosion will magnify any existing imperfections in the rock, and expand them into crevices. Heat expansion and contraction can lead to cracking. Rocks from one ledge can fall onto a ledge below (at least, this happens with sandstone, I don't know if it can happen with igneous or metamorphic rock). Alternatively, minerals leached from the rocks on one level might drip to a consistent place on a lower level, leading to stalagmites.

These will all create sheltered places where microorganisms (and eventually moss) can evolve. These microorganisms will evolve to adhere well to the rocks, and also to stabilise the rocks around them. Larger and larger mosses will evolve, as the previous generations make the landscape more hospitable. Perhaps this will lead to the formation of small, permanent pools of water, and eventually to the formation of parasitic organisms that eat the mosses. (You may want to check the science on this, I'm not sure if it's completely plausible, where the carbon was before life started moving it around, or whether the pools are necessary). At each generation, there's more and more shelter for life to develop. Eventually, there's enough shelter for soil to persist long enough for plants to evolve to grow in it.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I am going to have to make an huge assumption here.

This world is a constant cliff, overlooking oblivion. Applying physics, you cannot really have a constant air pressure unless:

Gravity works weird, pulling those on the cliff down and air towards the cliff face.

or

The world is really in some kind of finite system where air falls into oblivion and is constantly replenished and the same rate of loss. This, due to the regulated pressure and constant flow of air, should prevent a buildup pressure at the bottom. (Similar to a back pressure regulator in a water system.) However, I'm a little fuzzy on the physics of air pressure regulation based on its compressibility, but I will just assume that there can be a constant pressure maintained.

Assuming the constant pressure mechanism, there will be a constant flow of air rushing by the cliff face, causing significant erosion. This erosion will cause material to fall to ledges below. The lower the ledge, the more built up debris. This will allow more than just lichen to take root, producing more arable conditions further down. That is until the entire ledge is chocked full of debris that no one can make a home there.

from there, you can also add erosion due to water (which will also need to be replenished) and biological activities of plants and animals.